# Why Spring Boot parent starter modifies surefire defaults?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm migrating existing application to Spring Boot. To simplify project configuration I decided to setup `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent.

The problem is that surefire configuration

```
<configuration>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
   </includes>
   <excludes>
     <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
   </excludes>
</configuration>
```

is different than default surefire settings and broke my build.
How can I "undo" includes/excludes from Spring Boot? Not overwrite, but go back to surefire defaults.

I think that `spring-boot-starter-parent` should be surefire-neutral.

*PS. Sooner or later I will solve my problem myself. Current issue is rather question to Spring Boot*

Comment: How did it break your build?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I don't know yet details, but I have nested class like X$AbcTests which should not be executed by default, but when I adopted `spring-boot-starter-parent` the class has started to run. And fail.

Comment: You can override the config to whatever you want. We do name our tests `Tests`, that's why we override the config.

Comment: Yes I can override surefire and finally get back my build working. The question who is the recipient of `spring-boot-starter-parent`. If you, feel free to modify whatever you want. If me, please do not tamper with my project more than necessary

Comment: If you don't like our defaults, don't use the starter parent. You have a choice here so if you want to get full control over your projects without overriding things, do so. You can import the bom instead.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, unfortunately I have to downgrade jetty-version. With parent it is just one property to modify. Without parent I have to copy-paste many dependencies :(

Comment: Well it looks like you'd like the starter parent to do exactly what you want without changing anything. That can't happen I am afraid so please override the surefire settings and you'll be fine.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I finally found a solution. I was gawky and I still tried to modify `includes`, but my problem were with `excludes`. Anyway, although I undestood that your objective is reduce application complexity by providing sensible defaults, I think surefire configuration goes too far. My problem is rather unusual, but popular convention is that test class name ends with `Test` and your configuration breaks the convention. I think you should consider divide`spring-boot-starter-parent` into public and private parts

Comment: We consider `Tests` to be a sane default but I guess you go that by now. Again, there's nothing wrong with you disagreeing with us. The infrastructure is meant to be reconfigured like you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I restored surefire defaults for includes and excludes with

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```